# Случайный вывод ссылок из списка с уменьшением списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, случайные-числа

Хочу сделать, чтобы во время выполнения программы из списка из 100 ссылок выводилась одна случайная, потом другая случайная и так до момента пока список не станет пустым и не повторялась с предыдущей. При этом исходный список уменьшатся

```
import random




saity=['http://lenta.ru/rss/news','http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/main.xml','http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/news.xml','http://rssportal.ru/feed/173256.xml','http://www.levada.ru/rss.xml','http://wsrss.bbc.co.uk/russian/index.xml','http://inosmi.ru/misc/export/xml/rss/translation.xml','http://news.google.ru/news?ned=ru_ru&topic=t&output=atom','http://112.ua/rss','http://thebestvideo.net/feed','http://feeds.feedburner.com/Astrobene']
len_saity =len(saity)


for i in range(len_saity):
    len_saity =len(saity)
    print('len_saity '+str(len_saity))
    random1=int(random.randint(0, len_saity))
    print ('random1 '+str(random1))
    ssylka = str(saity([random1])) #wytaskiwajet
    del random1[random1]
    print ('ssylka '+str(ssylka))
    print ('список выглядит так: '+str(saity))
```

Ошибка выглядит так:

```
line 15, in <module>
    ssylka = str(saity([random1])) #wytaskiwajet
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [26]: saity=['http://lenta.ru/rss/news','http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/main.xml','http://www.kommersa
    ...: nt.ru/RSS/news.xml','http://rssportal.ru/feed/173256.xml','http://www.levada.ru/rss.xml','http
    ...: ://wsrss.bbc.co.uk/russian/index.xml','http://inosmi.ru/misc/export/xml/rss/translation.xml','
    ...: http://news.google.ru/news?ned=ru_ru&topic=t&output=atom','http://112.ua/rss','http://thebestv
    ...: ideo.net/feed','http://feeds.feedburner.com/Astrobene']
    ...:

In [27]: for i in reversed(range(len(saity))):
    ...:     print(saity.pop(random.randint(0, i)))
    ...:
http://inosmi.ru/misc/export/xml/rss/translation.xml
http://112.ua/rss
http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/news.xml
http://rssportal.ru/feed/173256.xml
http://news.google.ru/news?ned=ru_ru&topic=t&output=atom
http://feeds.feedburner.com/Astrobene
http://thebestvideo.net/feed
http://www.levada.ru/rss.xml
http://lenta.ru/rss/news
http://wsrss.bbc.co.uk/russian/index.xml
http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/main.xml
```

Или:

```
In [32]: while saity:
    ...:     print(saity.pop(random.randint(0, len(saity) - 1)))
```

Еще такой вариант, приближенный к вашему:

```
In [38]: while saity:
    ...:     elem = random.choice(saity)
    ...:     print(elem)
    ...:     saity.remove(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

При обращении к элементу списка круглые скобки не нужны. Поэтому и ошибка - вы обращаетесь к переменной как к функции. Так же в данном случае не нужно конвертировать  в строку, т.к. в списке уже лежат строки. Проблемную строчку кода нужно исправить на

```
ssylka = saity[random1]
```